# adding reference to System.Web.Mvc 3.0.0.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I got an old a .net application that is not mine. It was using the MVC 3.0.0.0 but I upgraded to the MVC 3.0.0.1. 
I am trying to make it run but I can not add the reference to System.Web.Mvc. I added the reference but next time I open it is unchecked.

I have to add that I am new with asp.net and MVC so maybe I am missing something obvious.

How should I add all the reference that I am missing?

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Did you try going into Solution Explorer ->  right clicking on Add Reference -> Assemblies / Framework -> Then click your desired reference version?

Comment: @BasicIsaac Yes, I just did again a couple times but the same thing. The next time I open the to add another reference System.Web.Mvc 3.0.0.1 is unchecked as well as the 4.0.0.1 I am using  .Net 4

Comment: @BasicIsaac Thanks It just worked I  just saw and the old reference to this library and I deleted and added again. Cheers,

Comment: I'll post it as answer then. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Solution Explorer -> right click on Add Reference -> Assemblies / Framework -> Then click your desired reference version.